# Rspec tags for tests without textual descriptions?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Pretty simple question, but I can't find an answer in the docs.
How can I add tags to specific Rspec examples that lack textual descriptions? For example, if you are using the fairly common ":focus" tag to select the tests you want to run (though that's not the only thing I need the tags for), you would, normally, write:

```
specify "the value should be 2", :focus => true do 
  @value.should be(2) 
end
```

However, it is not uncommon for simple tests to avoid redundancy to let the test itself do the talking and leave out the "the value should be 2" element, giving you something like:

```
context "the value" do
  subject{@value}
  it {should be(2)}
  it {should_not be(3)
end
```

However, I can't figure out how to add tags to that sort of test. Is this possible? Something like:

```
it :focus {should have_content("Oh yeah")}
```

Comment: Could you add more of an explanation to what you want?

Comment: Expanded the explanation, hopefully its more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

You were close, but Ruby won't parse `it :focus => true { ... }`. Try this:

`it(:focus => true) { should do_something }`

Comment: This parses, but it unfortunately doesn't actually work - rspec doesn't identify that argument as a tag, it identifies it as a string and simply names the example 'focustrue' while ignoring the effects of the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Try it! You may need to call `subject` before you do `it {should have_content('Oh yeah')}`.

Comment: Where is the :focus? The question was specifically about including a tag in the example.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear from your original statement. Will look at your rewrite.